# How to trim an array in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Say I have an array

```
array<double>^ buffer = gcnew array<double>(100);
```

And I want a function that does something like:

```
void foo(array<double>^% buffer)
{
    Array::Resize(buffer, 10);
}
```

but that don't allocate and/or move &buffer[0] when you want to trim the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET arrays are immutable in size once created. You **can't** trim it; you must reallocate and copy. So `Array.Resize` already does everything you need. Perhaps just ignore the elements at the end if you really don't want to do this.

Or; use a `List<T>`, which *encapsulates* an array, and *does* have `TrimExcess()`. In C# terms:

```
    var list = new List<int>(100);
    // prints 0/100
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", list.Count, list.Capacity);
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    // prints 3/100
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", list.Count, list.Capacity);
    list.TrimExcess();
    // prints 3/3
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", list.Count, list.Capacity);
```

Comment: I was afraid of so. I was thinking that ArraySegment might help but I think not.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in .NET. Arrays in .NET are of fixed size once allocated; the only way you can change the size of an array is to re-allocate it (which is what Array.Resize does), and this will invariably change the location of the array in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The recent C#/.NET Core versions come with a new type - `Span<T>` - which is essentially **a "view" into an existing array.**

Spans can be treated almost like arrays, you can iterate it via `foreach` etc.

They were invented just for this very purpose - to slice/trim/manipulate arrays without allocating new arrays. BUT you will have to rewrite your API to work with `Span` datatype (or, after all the array slicing/reslicing is complete, just call `ToArray()` at the end which will still allocate a new array, but only once all the work is finished)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0