# List<T> to T[] without copying

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm have a large list of value types that needs to be given to OpenGL. It would be great if this could happen as quickly as possible.
What I'm doing now looks like this:

```
List<Vertex> VList = new List<Vertex>();
... //Add vertices
Vertex[] VArray;
VList.CopyTo(VArray, VList.Length);
GL.SetData(..., VArray);
```

This list is easily 10MB big, so copying is slow. Can I do this without copying, like somehow get a pointer to the array used internally by List?

Or do I have to implement my own List class..

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I don't know the number of elements that will be added to the List.

Comment: @Iain, presumably, he doesn't know how many `Vertex` objects he will be using.

Comment: Because I don't know the length to begin with. I'd have to make a ridiculously large array and then resize it.

Comment: @Hannesh, my guess, because I haven't investigated, is that the backing array of the list will have many empty slots that will be filled during subsequent `Add` operations. This is to facilitate fast add operations without having to continually resize the array (it will, of course, do so as necessary). As a result, 1) a direct reference to the backing array might still need some cleaning. 2) If you're really concerned about performance, take note of this resizing and plan accordingly.

Comment: You can poke around using reflection, but the proper way is to roll your own. Just implement IList<T>.

Comment: @Anthony: Neither does the List<Vertex> :D @Hannesh, if you roll your own, make sure you profile it. Your IList implementation might be so much slower than List that the overhead is more than the gain.

Comment: Does anyone know why is not internal array exposed? I don't see any reasons why that could be harmful.

Comment: No need to implement your own list class. My [`InternalList<T>` struct](http://core.loyc.net/collections/internal-list.html) maximizes performance and allows access to the internal array. If you need it to be a class rather than a struct, copy and modify the [standalone version](https://gist.github.com/qwertie/7e1461f01b68defbe4bf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) interface isn't that difficult to do (well, not so long as Reflector is free and functioning, hint hint).

You can create your own implementation and expose the internal array as a public property.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with `IList<T>`, just wrap a `T[]` and introduce an `Add` method. `IndexOf`, `Insert`, etc.—not needed.

Comment: @Dan depends on the rest of his code.  If he was listening to our Master and Commander Jeffrey Richter, he'd be able to use his new collection on any method taking an IEnumerable, IList, IEnumerable<T>, etc etc etc.

Comment: @Will: Yes, hypothetically. Just sounds like a YAGNI situation to me. Especially the non-generic `IList` part (that's a whole other beast!). But since I have no idea what *else* he might be using this for, you're right; I could be completely wrong. Let me put it this way: if literally all I needed was an array that I could add to and still access as an array, I definitely would not bother implementing `IList<T>`. Maybe `IEnumerable<T>`, just because it's so trivial.

Comment: @Dan sokay, you struck a righteous blow.  He has to determine from his overall design if implementing the interface would be of any benefit.

Comment: @DanTao I have a similar problem but can't use IList<T> due to usage of some closed source API. I'm interested about the wrapping thing you said. Could you check out my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448350/get-array-from-list-without-heap-allocation

Answer (score 35):

If you need to access internal array repeatedly, it good practice to store accessor as delegate.

In this example, it's delegate to dynamic method. First call may not be fast, but subsequent calls (on List of same type) will be much faster.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    static class ArrayAccessor<T>
    {
        public static Func<List<T>, T[]> Getter;

        static ArrayAccessor()
        {
            var dm = new DynamicMethod("get", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, typeof(T[]), new Type[] { typeof(List<T>) }, typeof(ArrayAccessor<T>), true);
            var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load List<T> argument
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, typeof(List<T>).GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)); // Replace argument by field
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Return field
            Getter = (Func<List<T>, T[]>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<List<T>, T[]>));
        }
    }

    public static T[] GetInternalArray<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        return ArrayAccessor<T>.Getter(list);
    }
}
```

Make sure to include:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever seen! It is 10 times faster (according to my benchmarks) than the equivalent C# code.

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't recommend what you want to do. Why are you using a `List<T>` in the first place? If you can tell us precisely what characteristics the data-structure that you want to create should have, and how it should interface with the consuming API, we might be able to give you a proper solution to your problem.

But I will  try to answer the question as asked.

> Can I do this without copying, like
>   somehow get a pointer to the array
>   used internally by List?

Yes, although you would be relying on an undocumented implementation detail. As of NET 4.0, the backing array field is called `_items`.

```
Vertex[] vertices = (Vertex[]) typeof(List<Vertex>)
                   .GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                   .GetValue(VList);
```

Do note that this array will almost certainly have *slack* at the end (that's the whole point of `List<T>`), so `array.Length` on this array won't be all that useful.  The API that consumes the array would need to be notified of the "real" length of the array through other means (by telling it what the list's real `Count` was).

Comment: +1, but really, the OP should just create his own data structure.

Comment: Just cross your fingers that MS won't change the internal implementation in the next release...

Comment: What would you recommend instead of a List? I'm open to ideas.

Comment: @Hannesh roll your own implementation of `IList<T>`.

Comment: @Hannesh, actually, I was just suggesting that you re-implement `List<T>`, publicly exposing the internal array.

Comment: +1: very useful. And, as Marc Gravell points out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751345/how-to-trim-an-array-in-net) you will be stuck with the *slack* at the end, unfortunately. You will have to check for `null` or `.Empty()` for each element to prevent exceptions.

Comment: I'm not sure reinventing that particular wheel is necessarily the best approach. Determining initial capacity and expansion points becomes his problem, and it's not particularly likely he'll do a better job of it than the BCL team. I'd first suggest creating a list or array with high enough initial capacity to cover the average use case and then resize. Measure the performance and see if it is acceptable. If it isn't, investigate further.

Comment: I'm in agreement with others, derive your own collection from `IList<T>`.

Comment: @Anthony: problem is that resizing will copy the array - exactly what the OP doesn't want to do - and I don't blame him for the aversion to copying 10Mb to resize.

Comment: @IAbstract, my point is that he's going to need a high enough initial capacity, and he'll not guess the right size, so he's going to have empty slots. He's also likely not already providing an appropriate capacity, so he's already experiencing resize operations. Eliminate those, measure, and then go further as necessary.

Comment: @Anthony: internal resizing is performed based on the squared value of consecutive prime numbers so it does not (I believe) resize by a factor of 1 for each entry. Without knowing how large the array needs to be, then yes, your options are limited - **some** resizing will occur. I would still be inclined to derive a collection from IList<T> and modify the *internal* array's access.

Comment: @IAbstract, I was not implying it resized with *every* add operation. The point was merely that resize operations are very likely already happening. I'm suggesting worry about the *n* resize operations while he's processing before the *1* resize operation when he needs a reference to an array.

Comment: In particular, even if you create your own implementation of IList, you're still going to need to resize the array - as you add items, and then once you've added them all - unless you know in advance how many items there will be, or the consuming API doesn't care about the slack.

Comment: In fact, since they're value types, won't they be initialised to their default value? The consuming API may not even know the difference between a genuine entry, and the "slack".

Comment: I wouldn't hack into List<> with reflection, using undocumented fields is never a good idea -- who knows whether implementations differ across platforms and when mighty Microsoft might see fit to change the implementation. You also need to be cognisant of what the List<> is doing with the array -- there's a reason its an undocumented field.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a good way, but you can use **CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan** (since .net 5). It has access to the internal List array (see source code).

```
var list = new List<int>();
CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 6):

Rather than use reflection to access the internal array in a `List<T>`, if you only need the ability to *add*, then I would actually recommend implementing your own resizable array (gasp!). **It's not that hard.**

Something like:

```
class ResizableArray<T>
{
    T[] m_array;
    int m_count;

    public ResizableArray(int? initialCapacity = null)
    {
        m_array = new T[initialCapacity ?? 4]; // or whatever
    }

    internal T[] InternalArray { get { return m_array; } }

    public int Count { get { return m_count; } }

    public void Add(T element)
    {
        if (m_count == m_array.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref m_array, m_array.Length * 2);
        }

        m_array[m_count++] = element;
    }
}
```

Then you can get at the internal array with `InternalArray` and know how many items are in the array using `Count`.

Comment: I wouldn't want to make assumptions about how the consuming API will deal with the "slack" at the end of the array.

Comment: @Iain: Neither would I, but if it could accept a `length` parameter then that would be perfect. Otherwise I don't know what the OP could really be hoping for; I doubt he expected that `List<T>` resized its internal array by **1** on every call to `Add` (imagine that, guaranteed O(N) appends!).

Comment: @Lain obviously he'll have to take that into account.  OP is using it against the OpenGL stack, so I'd be willing to bet many of the methods OP is calling that take an array also take an array length.

Comment: @Iain: I look at it like this. The API definitely expects an *array*, otherwise the OP's question would *make no sense* (a `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable`, so he could just pass that otherwise). On the other hand, I assume it will optionally accept a `length` argument; otherwise the OP's hopes would be *futile*, since there'd be no way to avoid copying elements into a properly-sized array after all. If this is not the case, I think the OP's kinda screwed ;)

Comment: @Dan: Sorry, I was just saying it would be better if it *did* expect an IEnumerable. @Will: If so, no problem :)

Comment: I suggest that array access should be done via returning `ArraySegment<T>`.  In fact, that could be the internal mechanism for tracking the array and count together as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with reflection:

```
public static T[] GetUnderlyingArray<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    var field = list.GetType().GetField("_items",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (T[])field.GetValue(list);
}
```

edit: ah someone already said it while I was testing this..

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get a pointer out of a generic List, but I wouldn't recommend it and it probably wouldn't work the way you'd expect (if at all). Basically it means getting a pointer to an *object*, not a memory structure like an array.

I think you should go about this the other way around, and if you need speed then work directly on a byte array using structure array pointer in an unsafe context instead.

Background info:
"Even when used with the unsafe keyword, taking the address of a managed object, getting the size of a managed object, or declaring a pointer to a managed type is not allowed." - From [C#: convert generic pointer to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985646/c-convert-generic-pointer-to-array)

[MSDN unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Whoa -- all he wants is the array.  For example, the OP could *easily* just use reflection to get at it.  Not sure what all this business with unsafe code is about.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider if your approach to this is wrong. If you find yourself using reflection to do this - you've already lost.

I can think of a few ways to approach this though which one is ideal depends a lot on whether this is a multi-threaded piece of code or not.

Let's assume it's not ...

Think about the characteristics of the array. Each time this method is called an N-length array is created.  Your goal is to improve performance (which implies you want to minimize allocations and data copies).

Can you hint at compile or runtime what the ideal starting size for the array is?  I mean - if 95% of the time the N-length is 100k or less ... start with a 100k item array.  Keep using it until you hit a case where the array is too small.

When you hit this case you can decide what you do based on your understanding of the program. Should the array grow 10%? Should it grow to the literal needed length? Can you use what you have and continue the process for the rest of the data?

Over time the ideal size will be found. You can even have your program monitor the final size each time it runs and use that as a hint for allocation the next time it starts (perhaps this array length depends on environmental factors such as resolution, etc).

In other words - what I'm suggesting is that you not use the List-to-Array method and that you pre-allocate an array, keep it around forever, and grow it as needed.

If your program has threading issues you will obviously need to address those.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using GL I'll assume you know what you're doing and skip all the caveats. Try this, or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35588774/194921

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
  public struct ConvertHelper<TFrom, TTo>
      where TFrom : class
      where TTo : class {
    [FieldOffset( 0)] public long before;
    [FieldOffset( 8)] public TFrom input;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public TTo output;

    static public TTo Convert(TFrom thing) {
      var helper = new ConvertHelper<TFrom, TTo> { input = thing };
      unsafe {
        long* dangerous = &helper.before;
        dangerous[2] = dangerous[1];  // ie, output = input
      }
      var ret = helper.output;
      helper.input = null;
      helper.output = null;
      return ret;
    }
  }

  class PublicList<T> {
    public T[] _items;
  }

  public static T[] GetBackingArray<T>(this List<T> list) {
    return ConvertHelper<List<T>, PublicList<T>>.Convert(list)._items;
  }
```