# Get array from list without heap allocation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pointers, data-structures, heap-memory

I have a list and I want to assign its array to a property.

```
public void BuildMesh(List<Vector3> list){
    mesh.vertices=list.ToArray();
}
```

Now the problems:

- The project is game and is very tough on garbage collection so the default implementation of ToArray() is not an option as it creates a new array beside list's internal array.
- The mesh object is from a closed source API and the vertices property is a Vector3[] so can't assign a pointer to it.

Do I have any option to prevent heap allocation?

**EDIT: This is not a duplicate**

Can't use `IList<Vector3>`. The mesh is from a closed source API and needs Vector3[] so I can't assign `IList<Vector3>` to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List<T> to T\[\] without copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972951/listt-to-t-without-copying)

Comment: @VadimMartynov This is another question. The mesh is from a closed source API and needs Vector3[] so I can't assign IList<Vector3> to it.

Comment: if you have fixed size object simply don't dispose the object.  Instead simply mark the object unused.  Create a fixed array of objects at beginning of program.  Then mark object used or unused instead of creating and disposing the object.  No garbage collection required.

Comment: inner array in List is not same size as the actual items that you see. you may be able to do this with reflection but the reflection it self cause a lot mess than a simple ToArray. for example if you have 80 items you will get array of size 128 if you get the inner array directly. maybe reflection can help anyway if the list is too large. you have to test it your self.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That's the point. The inner array can't be used for the exact reason you mentioned it. In the case you described the inner array is 128 but I need an array with 80 members.

Comment: You can always make the object the largest size of any member.  It is easier to do things like this in C++ than C#, but can be done in C#.  So you really are building your own efficient garbage collector that doesn't fragment.

Comment: Is this Unity? If so, mesh.vertices is probably gonna do a copy anyway.

Comment: @Makubex Yes it's unity. But even if it's true, it would double the garbage creation if I do ToArray()

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using Unity. If I'm right, try `mesh.SetVertices(list)` which accept a `List<Vector3>`.

Comment: Yes it works. I am also curious to find a general solution to the problem.

Comment: I think it's not possible, because the inner array of List<T> could be bigger than its Count. If a specific number of vertices is used frequently like 64 vertices all the time, then you can try to reuse this array to prevent further heap allocation.

Comment: The Setvertices works perfectly with zero GC allocation. So my problem is essentially solved int this matter and I +1ed your answer. The question is also valid as a general C# issue. What if we face the situation in API other than unity?

Comment: I think it's about API design. If the API was designed to be typically used with reusable fixed-size buffers, then array is good, like System.IO.Stream API. Otherwise, the API is simply poorly designed.