# How can I access private List<T> members?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In general, in C# it is more convenient to use List than T[]. However, there are times when the profiler shows that List has significant performance penalties compared to natively-implemented bulk operations like Array.Copy and Buffer.BlockCopy. In addition, it is not possible to get pointers to List<> elements.

This makes working with dynamic meshes in Unity somewhat painful. Some of these problems could be alleviated if we could access **T[] List._items**. Is this possible to do without significant overhead? (either CPU or garbage)

Comment: Why don't implement a custom list for this case?

Comment: Because only custom APIs will accept custom lists. Platform APIs will not.

Comment: @PaulDuBois: Platform APIs *should* expect anything that implements [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which you can implement in your custom classes. Most examples in platform APIs that actually require instances of [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are sad monuments of API misdesign.

Comment: @PaulDuBois - just FWIW about all we do is dynamic mesh. I only ever use plain old arrays. To be clear, in any "general" Unity programming, I never ever use anything other than List, it's pointless bothering with array. But for mesh it's all array all the time. (In iOS I just get a block of ram and do it myself!)  Just purely FTR, a thought, I don't see any advantage whatsoever in using List when you're dealing at the mesh level. Everything you do you think algorithmically in offsets.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972951/listt-to-t-without-copying

Comment: Generally, one should avoid converting between data types per frame.  If the mechanism of choice _wants_ an array, then start of with an array in the first place.

Comment: @JoeBlow Our motivation for switching from T[] to List<T> for mesh data is that (once in steady state), they can be resized without reallocation. The resizing is a requirement for our particular use case; meshes start out dynamic, then when quiescent they are frozen (copied) into a large batch. ... If the dynamic mesh APIs took (T[], int count) or even better (T[], int start, int end) then that would be a good stopgap until the revamped buffer APIs show up.

Comment: Hi Paul!  "resized without reallocation .."  hmm, I'm not very sober but ultimately you have to write "the string of memory" - the array - of .vertices. I can't immediately see any algorithm where "resizing" would cause woes; I tend to have "chunks of" vertices hanging around in different arrays ... ("the dorsal fin!" "the tooth!" "the bending tooth" "the part Josh is doing!") and when it comes to making one big one for .vertices you just have to do that from the chunks.  Like I say, I am so old I think in memory - I don't even trust arrays man :-)

Comment: @JoeBlow A simplified problem statement: The user paints a brush stroke; this is an ever-lengthening array of verts. Each frame they're passed to mesh.SetVertices(), until the brush stroke ends at which point the verts are aggregated into a batch and the temp mesh reset. Mesh.SetVertices() doesn't take a count (yet), so you must pass a T[] or a List<T> of the correct size, or be OK with bogus/invisible data at the end. "Lengthening" a T[] incrementally from 1..N generates O(N^2) garbage, per brush stroke. Lengthening a preallocated, re-used List<T> generates no garbage!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you but when doing that type of brushstroke, I just have an array of say 10000 length.  (Obviously I keep note of where the "end" is.) If the 10000 becomes too small, allocate another... again I may definitely be misunderstanding you but that's the only way i've seen a brushstroke (or "road" or whatever) done... like I say, I don't even trust frickin' arrays, I'd rather have a chunk of memory allocated :) We just did an interesting one that grew a "3D brushtroke" into Oculus - I'm pretty sure no higher performance (at the "using memory/lists/arrays" level) is poss....

Comment: I fully appreciate I may have no clue what you're doing; if you have many people drawing many strokes at once (or something bizarre/amazing!) and incredibly *memory* is becoming an issue .. I mean I'd have to think about it.  When you say "brushstroke", thank God in normal use that's only "growing at one end" ........ but you may have something wild like, different things are happening to the "previous body" of it? as it goes? In that case, some sort of troubling "chunky-chunks-of-array" would be the only way forward.

Comment: Memory = garbage; garbage = garbage collection; garbage collection = hitches, since this all needs to run at 90fps.

Comment: Oh, and regarding the "array of say 10000", yes; as long as you're cool with having unused data at the end, (and the need to null it back out when you re-use the array), that is the second-best approach.

Comment: (oh, and of course .. above i mention 10k chunks ..  just take the full size (64k or whatever the limit is in Unity) rather than 10k chunks, if easier and relevant.)

Comment: "Memory = garbage .. collection"  Hmm, not with you there.  I take all the memory I need when the program opens, and keep it until the user sells the iPad or PC.  I can't see any situation where you'd ever let go of your *working metal* when dealing with mesh like that; you'd never involve GC in any way at all.  To weave mesh is to deal with the metal eh?! So much better than programing frickin' reactive web layouts of Facebook forms!!  :)

Comment: 90fps is no problem.  BTW if painting strokes, did you grab Vectrosity, everyone uses it - check out eric's kode. Even if just a placehodler while you do other stuff you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the layout of List, then you can use a dirty trick to cast managed object references. Do not use this unless you're willing to test on every target platform you run on, and re-test with every Unity upgrade.

The most dangerous thing about this is that it breaks invariants about the runtime and compiled type of the object. The compiler will generate code for an object of type TTo, but the object's RTTI field will still show an object of type TFrom.

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
  public struct ConvertHelper<TFrom, TTo>
      where TFrom : class
      where TTo : class {
    [FieldOffset( 0)] public long before;
    [FieldOffset( 8)] public TFrom input;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public TTo output;

    static public TTo Convert(TFrom thing) {
      var helper = new ConvertHelper<TFrom, TTo> { input = thing };
      unsafe {
        long* dangerous = &helper.before;
        dangerous[2] = dangerous[1];  // ie, output = input
      }
      var ret = helper.output;
      helper.input = null;
      helper.output = null;
      return ret;
    }
  }

  class PublicList<T> {
    public T[] _items;
  }

  public static T[] GetBackingArray<T>(this List<T> list) {
    return ConvertHelper<List<T>, PublicList<T>>.Convert(list)._items;
  }
```

Comment: again just purely FWIW, I have never, ever been able to get anything like this to work reliably (as you suggest).

Comment: If you can remember and share specifics, that would be very useful.

Comment: I get an error executing: System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Could not load type 'StructPerf.BackingArray`1' from assembly 'StructPerf, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because generic types cannot have explicit layout.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection is always possible. This generates a few hundred bytes of garbage for the call to **GetValue()**. It is also not very fast; on the order of 40 List< T > accesses.

```
  // Helper class for fetching and caching FieldInfo values
  class FieldLookup {
    string sm_name;
    Dictionary<Type, FieldInfo> sm_cache;
    public FieldLookup(string name) {
      sm_name = name;
      sm_cache = new Dictionary<Type, FieldInfo>();
    }
    public FieldInfo Get(Type t) {
      try {
        return sm_cache[t];
      } catch (KeyNotFoundException) {
        var field = sm_cache[t] = t.GetField(
          sm_name,
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField |
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        return field;
      }
    }
  }

  static FieldLookup sm_items = new FieldLookup("_items");

  public static T[] GetBackingArray<T>(this List<T> list) {
    return (T[])sm_items.Get(typeof(List<T>)).GetValue(list);
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand that  :)

Comment: Unless you are using .NET Reflection Caching, one should avoid using reflection in games due to the performance hit

Comment: This answer quantifies the performance _and_ the memory hit for one particular platform (Unity, Mono, desktop), allowing the reader to decide for themself, according to their particular requirements, whether they should avoid reflection in games.