# How to efficiently convert IList<byte> to byte[]?

Tags: c#, opencv, xamarin

I have problem with efficiently converting an `IList<byte>` to `byte[]`. I'm working with Xamarin Studio with OpenCV to process images and Fotoapparat to take pictures. 
I want to convert the list to an array because OpenCV expects an array not a list. I know the 'easy' way to convert with `ToArray()`, but it takes too much time (more than 8-9 sec to convert).  For reference, my `IList<byte>` has a length of 5564448.

Does anybody know how to efficiently convert `IList<byte>` to `byte[]`?

Comment: Why are you storing 5 MB of data in a List<byte> in the first place?

Comment: Not without knowing the concrete class thats implementing the IList. For all we know, it could be a FileStream - so the cost of conversion is related to the underlying interface implementation.

Comment: I doubt there is a better way.  Have you looked up the source code?

Comment: It seems like your `IList<T>` has a slow implementation of `CopyTo` implementation, since that's what `ToArray` uses. But you didn't tell us which implementation of `IList<T>` you're using, and why (if you need a variable length buffer, `MemoryStream` works).

Comment: Consider updating the openCV wrappers to use `Span` and `ReadOnlySpan`, that way there's no copying to do.

Comment: It's all about library fotoapparat and binding it to xamarin studio... For unintelligible reasons, library delivers image frame in IList<byte> type, instead of byte[]. I wrote all of information about used frameworks, but some moderator change my post....

Comment: @bnk what is the actual type that is delivered? You can inspect that while debugging... that would be useful to know.

Comment: The real type is Android.Runtime.JavaArray<byte>

Comment: @bnk have you tried to use [CopyTo](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Runtime.JavaArray%3CT%3E.CopyTo/p/T[]/System.Int32/) method that JavaArray provides?

Comment: Yup, I tried and still takes much time...

Comment: @bnk I have just check the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JavaArray.cs) for JavaArray. It uses `JNIEnv.GetArray<T>(Handle)` to retrieve the array. You can work around this  by using reflection and calling that method. Check specifically the implementation of `IndexOf` method

Comment: The approach I suggest is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308019/4430204) answer... Only that instead of accessing an internal field you will be calling an internal (or private.. not sure) method

Comment: I saw your suggestion, but srsly dont know how can i invoke `JNIEnv.GetArray<T>(Handle)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my own problem. Maybe someone will have the same problem in future.
Below solution:

```
internal static IntPtr javaClassHandle;
internal static IntPtr classRef
{
    get
    {
        return JNIEnv.FindClass("io/fotoapparat/preview/Frame", ref javaClassHandle);
    }
}
static IntPtr imageJFieldId;

public void ProcessFrame(Frame frame)
{            
    int bufferSize = frame.Image.Count;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    if (imageJFieldId == IntPtr.Zero)
        imageJFieldId = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(classRef, "image", "[B");
    var fieldObject = JNIEnv.GetObjectField(frame.Handle, imageJFieldId);
    var fastByteArray = new FastJavaByteArray(fieldObject);
    fastByteArray.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
}
```

Link to [FastJavaByteArray](https://github.com/jamesathey/FastAndroidCamera/blob/master/FastJavaByteArray.cs)