Fastest way to access the array in a List<byte>
I have a List<byte> which want to convert to a byte[]. It might become pretty large, so I do not want to make the system copy the whole underlying array to a newly allocated array.
Is there any way to not cause a new array to be allocated and the values to be copied? I do not use the list anymore after "casting" it to an array.
This is my current code:
List<byte> write_buffer;
T item;

public byte[] Serialize() {
    write_buffer = new(65536);
    item.Serialize(this);
    return write_buffer.ToArray(); // This is slow
}

I do not use the list stored in "write_buffer" anymore after converting it to an array. Do I need to write my own list implementation to use the underlying array directly? And if so, is there a realloc (from the C standard library) equivalent that is not unsafe?

Related / possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972951/listt-to-t-without-copying.

@wohlstad yes it is. I shall close my question. Thank you, that solved my question.

Note that the new way to do this is not in the top answer there, it's in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73448899/14868997 which is CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan

Thank you @Charlieface I tired that but I think the language version of my project is too low. CollectionsMarshal does not exist yet for me. In the end I just implemented it as an array anyway, because I needed it to act as a queue or as a stack depending on the objects state. It was more comfortable for me this way.
